# Yield number into parts smaller than a threshold in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, generator

Assuming I have a number `n=22500` and a threshold `t=10000`, I want to have a function that yields: `10000`, `10000`, `2500`.

How do I do this? My non-working attempt because once you go over 20000 it returns numbers larger than 10000.

```
def chunk(number):
    steps = 10000
    if number > steps:
        yield steps
        yield number - steps
    else:
        yield number

for i in chunk(35000):
   print(i)

# prints (wrongly):
# 10000
# 25000
```

Or is there a builtin library for this?

Comment: Can you give a little more detail on how many numbers you want the original number to be split. Also, do they have to be multiples of 1000 for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be cleaned up a bit, so check back for edits over the next few minutes, but what about:

```
def chunk(num, thresh):
    while True:
        if num > thresh:
            num -= thresh
            yield thresh
        else:
            yield num
            break

for x in chunk(22500, 10000):
    print(x)
```

**Output**

```
10000
10000
2500
```

**Edit:**

Consider:

```
def chunk(num, thresh):
    while num:
        to_yield = min(num, thresh)
        yield to_yield
        num -= to_yield

for x in chunk(22500, 10000):
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using division (floor) and modulus operators:

```
def chunk(number, step):
    for i in range(number // step):
        yield step
    rem = number % step
    if rem:
        yield rem

for i in chunk(22500, step=10000):
    print(i)

10000
10000
2500
```

Comment: yours is nicer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop to make sure it works with any amount:

```
def chunk(number):
    steps = 10000
    while number > 0:
        yield min(number, steps)
        number -= steps

for i in chunk(35000):
   print(i)

# prints:
# 10000
# 10000
# 10000
# 5000
```